# Table with self relation overwriting itself

Tags: google-app-maker

I am having an issue with a table with self relations lets call it Table1

I created a table with two fields Id and name
Then i created a one to many relation from this Table1 to Table1 where one parent record can have many child records

Then i created a page lets call it Page1

This page has an insert for where you enter the name and select a parent record

This issue is that when i create a record and select a parent record. the first time i reload the application it takes the parent and makes the parent of that parent the child record.

Example I enter the following data in the insert form

```
Id        Name           Parent
1         USA            No Selection
2         Canada         No Selection
3         Houston        USA
4         Toronto        Canada
5         Minute Maid    Houston
```

This goes fine, but when I refresh the application the data changes to

```
Id        Name           Parent
1         USA            Houston
2         Canada         Toronto
3         Houston        Minute Maid
4         Toronto        Canada
5         Minute Maid    Houston
```

if i change it back it stays correct until i make a new entry then the issue repeats. Any ideas on what is causing this issue?

[image: Page View]

[image: Relation]

[image: Table]

[image: Test1]

[image: Test2]

Comment: Sounds like the issue might be in your model create event or in your create form. Your self relation should have names associated with it like Table1 (on the one side) and Table1Relation (on the many side) for example. Do you have any code in your create form or in your model create event that relates a newly created record?

Comment: No code at all. Actually made a table just to test this out with the same info i posted to make sure there was no issues with code or anything else, think it might be an app maker bug?

Comment: named the relations Child(Many), Parent(one)

Comment: So what is in your form? Just a field for Name, or is there like a dropdown for parent also? What is your desired result? If there is a dropdown for the create form what are the bindings for the dropdown? I think maybe there is some misconception as to how a self relation should work in this case and I potentially see some issues with storing country, city, and company name all in the same table and then creating relationships between them.

Comment: just the free text field for name and the dropdown for parent. everything is default. the binding is default to @datasources.SelfRelationsTest.items. SelfRelationsTest is the actual table name. I am trying to use this function for a multi level asset category heirarchy where the number of levels have the potential to change, just did the example with cities states.

Comment: Added some screen shots. I think it is something with the create form. I may just be better off scripting it off of a button click instead of using the default create form.